# How can I refactor my 'view' code to display items per year?

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose, ejs

I would like to refactor a piece of code in order to display / regroup my items per year without repeating the code for each of the years. As of now, I've tried looping through an array of years, but it didn't seem to work.

Here is the piece of code I'm currently repeating in a 'view' file (ejs template) for 8 different years :

```
<ul><h3>YEAR 2017:</h3>
 <% items.forEach(function(el){ %>
  <% if(el.date.substring(7, 11) == "2017"){ %>
   <li><%= el.date %>: 
   <% if(el.url){ %>
    <a href="<%= el.url %>" title="<%= el.title %>"><%= el.title %></a>,
   <% }else{ %> 
    <%= el.title %>,
   <% } %>
   <% if(el.by){ %>
    <%= el.type %>, <%= el.by %>
   <% }else{ %>
    <%= el.type %>
   <% } %>
   @ <%= el.location %></li>
  <% } %>
 <% }); %>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you are already on the right track by using an ejs template and using an array. Maybe you should restructure the way you are passing the items so that they are in an array of objects like so

items = [{"year": 2016, "items": [item1,item2...]},{"year":2017, "items": [item1,item2..]}, ... ]

Then you could loop through them in this way:

```
<% items.forEach(function(year){ %>
    <ul><h3>YEAR <%= year.year %>:</h3>
        <% year.items.forEach(function(el){ %>
        ...
        <% } %>
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe like this, please convert to eje syntax:

```
let arr = []

let arrEl = items.map(function(el, index){
  return el.date.substring(7, 11);
})
arr.push(arrEl)

for (let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
  items.map(function(element, index){
    if(el.date.substring(7, 11) == arr[i]){
      //show your el
    }
  })
}
```